# Can I connect a SATA III drive to a SAS controller and get the SATA III performance?

Tags: sata, sas

Can I connect a SATA III drive to a SAS controller and get the SATA III performance? Will I see slower performance from the SATA III drive by using a SAS controller than a SATA III controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the SAS controller supports sata3 you can, If not it will go back to sata2.
If the disk is not a SSD or in a raid you will never get sata3 or sata2 max speeds

Name on your sas controller ?

Comment: Actually, even if it's in RAID, you probably still won't get anywhere near the SATA III port speed. In the case of RAID, you're looking at the backplane as the limiting factor, not the individual ports.

Comment: @MarkM What is the backplane?